# Windows 10 File Browser popup menu showing New items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, contextmenu, explorer

Using:
Visual Studio 2017
Windows Form
C#

I know how to create a Popup menu displaying items that I have added with code to a native WinForm ContextMenuStrip control.

For example:
[My coded Popup menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzK9A.png)

What I am looking for and trying to achieve and I have not found so far is how to populate a ContextMenuStrip or any alternative control with the Items that show up when you right click on a blank space on **File Explorer and select New** and displays a list of the Items you can create base on what you have installed on your computer.

For example:
[File Explorer Popup Menu > New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK2lq.png)

I have looked at many suggestion on different sites but they all show what I already know in how to add items manually and none explain how to add the Items that show up in the **File Explorer New sub menu**.

Could anyone tell me if this is even possible and/or point me to the right place.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You're describing the problem as if it were some programming task, so most probably, it's not the thing you expect to see. Adding items to that menu is more of a problem of configuration of the almighty 'explorer.exe'..

Please [see here](https://www.howtogeek.com/290500/how-to-add-other-file-types-to-the-new-item-menu-in-windows-10s-file-explorer/) and read where to place item templates and how to register "file classes" for them in the registry.

I don't like answers like this that just drop a link to other resource, but it's not reasonable to copy&paste&redact it all not knowing if it's what you really want..

Also, note that if you see your desktop, then 'explorer.exe' is already running, and editing its configuration in the registry probably won't take any effect until this process is restarted. Typically you get advices like in that article above:

> To have this change take effect, you need to restart your PC, not just sign out and back in.

But that's not true. Just kill explorer.exe via task manager, and then start it back again. No need to reboot.